# How to get gmtime datestring as a variable?

Tags: perl

I have code snippet which I modified, from here:

[How can I get this week's dates in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916522/how-can-i-get-this-weeks-dates-in-perl)

I am trying to generate dates, preferably starting today, up to any number of days. My code works from tomorrow up to 10 days. I do generate an array `@dates` containing strings like `Sat 08 Apr 2023`.

I am not able to extract a datestring like `$dates[0]`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX qw{strftime};

my @dates;
my $dates;

my $time = time ();
my $seconds = 24*60*60;
my @time = gmtime ();

for (1..10){
 $time += $seconds;
 my @dates = gmtime ($time);
 print strftime ("%a %d %b %Y\n", @dates);
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you want. The code you posted literally produces a "GMT date string" as you asked.

Comment: Are you asking how to append a string to an array???

Comment: I want to use $dates[0], $dates[1], ... individually as variables. Right now I can only <print strftime("%a %d %b %Y\n", @dates)>. I am not able to extract a particular date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Original answer (don't do this)

The following code is the minimum change to do what you want, but as @brian d foy already pointed out, will not work in all circumstances:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX qw{strftime};

my @dates;
my $time = time ();
my $seconds = 24*60*60;

for (1..10){
 push @dates, strftime ("%a %d %b %Y\n", gmtime ($time));
 $time += $seconds;
}
print @dates;
```

produces:

```
Sun 09 Apr 2023
Mon 10 Apr 2023
Tue 11 Apr 2023
Wed 12 Apr 2023
Thu 13 Apr 2023
Fri 14 Apr 2023
Sat 15 Apr 2023
Sun 16 Apr 2023
Mon 17 Apr 2023
Tue 18 Apr 2023
```

### Improved answer

The code below, apart from being shorter, should also work in the corner cases that @brian d foy was talking about.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Date::Calc qw( Today Add_Delta_Days Date_to_Text );
my @dates;
my @date = Today();
for (0..9){
    push @dates, Date_to_Text( Add_Delta_Days(@date,$_) )."\n";
}
print @dates;
```

Comment: Thank you very much @DobbyTheElf, this partially solves my problem, in the sense that I am able to print \@dates as well as individual elements of the array \@dates.  My intention is to get dates from today or tomorrow, not necessarily from Monday or Sunday. So my "for (1..10)" was meant to mean from tomorrow, whatever day tomorrow is.

Comment: Don't do this. You can't merely add a certain number of seconds to a time and get the next date. It seems like a simple problem, but there are certain dates in certain locales where this might fail. Something like DateTime, which you already have examples of from the answer you linked in the question, show you how to do this reliably.

Comment: @brian d foy - In my original answer, I concentrated more on the logic of what the OP was trying to achieve, but you are absolutely right. I've improved the answer to address your concern.

Comment: You should remove the broken code too.